# org-mode warning when scheduling task on top of another task?

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** how can I make `org-mode` warn me when I'm about to schedule a task on top of another task?

I frequently schedule tasks or meetings (with `org-deadline` or `org-schedule`) at a specific hour on some day in the distant future.  However, I rarely remember what I already have scheduled on that day, and often discover later that I have double-booked a time slot.

Example: I use `org-deadline` to schedule a meeting for next Thursday from 9am-10am, but already have a preexisting meeting next Thursday from 8:30am-10:30am.

Is there any way, when entering a timestamp/scheduled event/deadline, to have `org-mode` warn me when I'm about to double-book a timeslot?

Comment: Can you please provide some of your `org-todo-keywords`, so that I (or another forum participant) can give a precise sample answer?  Just the ones used with deadlines and scheduling are sufficient.

Comment: @lawlist: nothing fancy: TODO, WORK, DONE. I rarely use the actual keywords, though.

Comment: `(defun example () "Doc-string." (interactive) (goto-char (point-max)) (while (re-search-backward "\\* \\(TODO\\|WORK\\|DONE\\)" nil t) (unless (org-at-heading-p) (org-back-to-heading t)) (let* ( (element (org-element-at-point)) (todo-state (org-element-property :todo-keyword element)) (deadline (ignore-errors (org-element-property :deadline element))) (deadline-time-stamp (ignore-errors (time-to-days (org-time-string-to-time (org-element-property :raw-value deadline))))) (today (time-to-days (current-time))) (title (org-element-property :title element)) ) INSERT-CONDITIONS-HERE )))`

Comment: I have some other projects that need to get out the door this morning, but will check back later today to see if this issue has been resolved.  The above draft example needs a similar section for `scheduled`.  The example illustrates how to extract various values from an org-mode todo entry.

Answer (score 3):

This example contemplates the existence of the following criteria:

- A range of time for a particular meeting / appointment is not presently supported.  The initial testing has been done with only one start time -- e.g., `DEADLINE: <2014-12-01 Mon 08:30>  SCHEDULED: <2014-12-01 Mon>`
- "TODO", "WORK" and "DONE" are among some of the `org-todo-keywords` that have been predefined by the user.
- Line 21 needs to be modified with the name of the `*.org` buffer that contains the TODO that need to be checked against for availability.  This is the raw `*.org` file (which *must* already be in the major-mode `org-mode`), NOT an `*Org Agenda*` buffer.  In my testing, the `*.org` buffer is named `.todo`
- The example checks both deadlines and scheduled time-stamps.
- The regexp is looking for just one star to the left of the keyword -- it can be tweaked to be more precise to match the needs of the user.
- The example assumes the `*.org` buffer (containing the TODO to be checked against) is already open -- burried or visible will work.

It is certainly possible to get more elaborate by creating a custom `org-read-date` function that performs the check when manually entering a time-stamp; however, that is beyond the scope of this basic example.

Another idea would be to use the `check-availability` function following the usage of `org-deadline` -- i.e., the let-bound variable `date-time` (in this example) would be set to `(org-time-string-to-time org-last-inserted-timestamp)`.

```
(defun check-availability (&optional date)
"Doc-string."
(interactive)
  (let* (
      not-available
      (date (if date date (read-string "Date:  ")))
      (date-parsed (parse-time-string date))
      (date-time
        (cond
          ((and
               (not (null (nth 0 date-parsed)))
               (not (null (nth 1 date-parsed)))
               (not (null (nth 2 date-parsed))))
            (date-to-time date))
          ((and
              (null (nth 0 date-parsed))
              (null (nth 1 date-parsed))
              (null (nth 2 date-parsed)))
            (date-to-time (concat date " 00:00")))))
      (date-seconds (time-to-seconds date-time)) )
    (with-current-buffer (get-buffer ".todo")
      (save-excursion
        (goto-char (point-max))
        (catch 'found
          (while (re-search-backward "\\* \\(TODO\\|WORK\\|DONE\\)" nil t)
            (unless (org-at-heading-p)
              (org-back-to-heading t))
            (let* (
                (element (org-element-at-point))
                (deadline (org-element-property :deadline element))
                (deadline-seconds
                  (when deadline
                    (time-to-seconds
                      (org-time-string-to-time
                        (org-element-property :raw-value deadline)))))
                (scheduled (org-element-property :scheduled element))
                (scheduled-seconds
                  (when scheduled
                    (time-to-seconds
                      (org-time-string-to-time
                        (org-element-property :raw-value scheduled))))) )
              (when
                  (or
                    (and
                      deadline-seconds
                      (= date-seconds deadline-seconds))
                    (and
                      scheduled-seconds
                      (= date-seconds scheduled-seconds)))
                (setq not-available t)
                (throw 'found (message "Not Available!")))))))
      (unless not-available 
        (message "Congratulations -- you are available!")))))
```

Comment: +1. Consider adapting your let statement to follow standard elisp indentation.

Comment: Thanks for thoughts -- it gives me a few useful ideas to proceed.  It's not yet doing what I had in mind, however, in part because I'm trying to have `org-deadline` and `org-schedule` warn me when I'm about to double-book something, while this function would be a separate step to check dates/times in the first place.  (That's also a useful bit of functionality I hadn't thought of, by the way!)

Comment: Agreed, this answer is only meant to be a launching point -- i.e., a step in the right direction.  It is possible for you to make this very elaborate, including displaying the day calendar in a separate buffer so that you can adjust your schedule (rather than just receive a warning message).  `org-deadline` sets the variable `org-last-inserted-timestamp` -- that might be an ideal place to introduce your check-availability function -- the let-bound variable `date-time` (in this example) would be set to `(org-time-string-to-time org-last-inserted-timestamp)`.  And, you'll need to add ranges.